# How to edit docker volume device option?

Tags: linux, docker, mount, docker-machine, docker-volume

How could I change the docker-volume-device option after the creation, With out removing the container

### Previous command used for creation

```
     docker volume create \
          --driver local \
          --opt type=none \
          --opt device="/home/userA/Containers/vol1/home" \
          --opt o=bind \
          $DOCKER_VOLUME_NAME
```

### Current Status

```
    $ docker volume inspect vol1
    [
        {
            "CreatedAt": "XXX",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Labels": {},
            "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/vol1/_data",
            "Name": "vol1-home",
            "Options": {
                "device": "/home/userA/Containers/vol1/home",
                "o": "bind",
                "type": "none"
            },
            "Scope": "local"
        }
    ]
```

Is there any way we can safely alter the value of device "/home/userA/Containers/vol1/home" to "/Containers/vol1/home". I am not want to keep this in specific user.

I would like to change
*" --opt device="/home/userA/Containers/vol1/home" "*

### I would like to see

```
    $ docker volume inspect vol1
    [
        {
            "CreatedAt": "XXX",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Labels": {},
            "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/vol1/_data",
            "Name": "vol1-home",
            "Options": {
                "device": "/Containers/vol1/home",
                "o": "bind",
                "type": "none"
            },
            "Scope": "local"
        }
    ]
```

Does any one have any suggestion for my problem?

### **Reason / Benefit of this:**

Due to a lack of space in my disk, I moved all files from /var/lib/docker to some other disk and I mounted them as  /var/lib/docker.  I saved my OS space and separated docker from the os disk.

Now I am trying to separate the volume device also. so I can save more space, Unfortunately, I might lose my container data for doing so.

Comment: Since the volume will have different backing storage, it shouldn't make a difference if you delete and recreate it; it will fundamentally be a different volume either way  You'll have to stop, delete, and recreate any containers using this volume, but that should also be very routine.

Comment: I can recreate the container using this volume, But it never makes any difference. Becouse device option is configured in the volume.

Comment: I would like to change the device option without loosing the data

Comment: You need to physically move the volume?  You'll have to do that outside of Docker.  With this particular construction Docker doesn't "know" that it has a bind-mounted host directory, it happens to be a combination of generic Linux mount options that constructs a bind mount.

Comment: @DavidMaze I am ready to copy it physically. As per your comment, It is not possible to do so.

Comment: Hi, I have a very similar scenario. did yo get to solve this problem?